# Error with converting numbers to text

Tags: c++

Im writing a c++ program that convert numbers to text.

I got two problems(edit: just one now):

- The first problem is that the program only write out the numbers as 1-19 correct, everything from 20-99 such as when i wrote 34 for an example, the answear i get is thirty and not thirtyfour as it should be. After thirty it just comes errors and the program shut down. [Problem fixed]
- The second problem is that i wish i could write numbers between 0-999 and not only 99 but im not sure how to do that

  ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;


  int main()
    {
   int num, Ldight, Rdight;

      string ones[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
              "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
              "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",  "fifteen",
              "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

  string tens[] = {"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty", "sixty","seventy","eighty", "ninety"};


      cout << "Pick a number between 1-99: ";
      cin >> num;

        if(num <= 0)
            {
          cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
            }

     else if (num >= 0 && num <= 19)
            {
  cout << "Your number is: " << ones[Rdight] ;
            }

     else if (num >=20 && num <=99)
      {
  Rdight = num % 10;
  Ldight = num / 10;

  cout << "Your number is: " << tens[Ldight - 2] << ones[Rdight];
       }

  return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Please format your code correctly before posting. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

You should change this:

```
cout << "Your number is: " << tens[Ldight - 2] << ones[num];
```

To

```
cout << "Your number is: " << tens[Ldight - 2] << ones[Rdight];
```

You compute a value you never use. And also in the line above `ones` num accesses index out of bounds.

Comment: "ones" is valid for numbers 0..19.

Comment: @MatsPetersson and we are in the case when `num>=20`. For numbers greater than 20 we never use values for 10 or more.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you means "ALSO in the line above [not the one copied here, but the previous one doing something similar]". I see what you mean. I also like to have people think for themselves in obvious "this is homework" questions, I didn't give the exact change, just some hints...

Comment: @Mats I would usually agree with you, but imho this question is a clear case of "knew the right thing to do, did the wrong thing, stared at the code for too long to notice" - I don't see any harm in giving the exact solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, your problem is in this line:

```
cout << "Your number is: " << tens[Ldight - 2] << ones[num];
```

You are using the wrong variable, although correctly calculating the value in the lines just above. I'm not telling you how to fix it, as you are the one learning programming, and you need to learn how to spot this type of problem.

[I personally would add two dummy fields to "tens", so as you don't have to do `-2` as well - that's a small price to pay].

As for your second problem, you'll have to consider how you go about saying it, and you'll probably come up with something... It's not VERY different from solving single digits, let's say.  If you need more than about half a dozen or so lines, you are solving it wrong.

And once you have solved hundreds, it will be very trivial to add numbers up to millions, and even much further, with just a few lines of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line :

cout << "Your number is: " << tens[Ldigit - 2] << ones[**Rdigit-1**];

There is no need for element "zero" in ones[] since you output as **error** when i/p <= 0 , so remove element **"zero"**

Answer (score -1):

You could try by splitting user input to 2 pieces.
If user input is : 55 you split it in 5 and 5 and then print

tens[5] + ones[5]

That would be much better solution.
You will delete all those if-s that can cause problems

Comment: No, you won't get rid of the `if`s, unless you redefine the English language so that "ten-three" et cetera are valid words.